# CSS - Not applying media query

Tags: html, css

I wrote media query for my HTML code, but not applying. I have to show my text in center in small screen.

```css
@media(max - width: 400 px) {
    h1 {
      text - align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Search for a Doctor or Care Provider</h1>
```

How to fix?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/puvazedimo/1/edit?html,css,output — I can't reproduce the problem. The code you have works fine when I test it.

Comment: If a awnser worked for you, please mark it as the correct awnser

Answer (score 2):

The problem that @Zvezdas1989 is removing is that you had a space between 400 and px, they need to be together, just like the `max-width` and the `text-align`.

```
@media(max-width: 400px) {
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

So that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not applying because of the spaces, you need to remove those in order to make it valid:

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Search for a Doctor or Care Provider</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the spaces, like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Friends</h1>
```